# Avoid Christmas tree in Git log --all

Tags: git, git-log

I recently created a `release` branch in which I merged all the tagged commits. The goal is to rename `master` into `develop` then use `master` as a `release` branch (git-flow like)

Now, when I display my full log with `git log --all` I get a wonderful Christmas tree not really helpful.

```
* | e503add 10 days ago 
| *   a2948b1 11 days ago 
| |\
| * \   b22e247 3 weeks ago 
| |\ \
| * \ \   01f1ebc 4 weeks ago   
| |\ \ \
| * \ \ \   01336c7 4 weeks ago  
| |\ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \   59f83a8 5 weeks ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \   25a2444 6 weeks ago  
| |\ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \   4271ae9 6 weeks ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \   ef62400 8 weeks ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   f56aa1e 2 months ago
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   7fdab4a 4 months ago  
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   b25d101 4 months ago
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   7477021 6 months ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   8b166b4 8 months ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   93be56f 9 months ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   7b28785 1 year, 4 months ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   4aaa409 1 year, 4 months ago
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   4cab662 1 year, 5 months ago 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   996564a 1 year, 6 months ago
```

One solution is to use `git log --date-order` instead of the default `--topo-order`. However I cannot really explain why I get such log.

I created my release branch using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
git checkout -b release $first-tag
for tag in "${tags[@]}"
do
    date=$(git show -s --format="%ad" $(git log -n1 --format=%h $tag))
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$date;
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$date;
    git merge -Xtheirs -m $tag $tag
    git tag --delete $tag
    git tag -a -m $tag $tag
done
```

How can I avoid this Christmas tree in `--topo-order`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--topo-order` does not behave good with multiple heads [*]. If you want nice picture try using it with specific branch instead of `--all` (`release` in your case).

[*] A commit must be after any commit it is merged to, so if some previous release commit is placed after your current release it forces all branches down, causing the tree.

example script to reproduce the issue as I see it:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git init
git commit --allow-empty -m init
git tag init
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
 sleep 1
 git commit --allow-empty -m b$i
 git branch b$i
 git reset --hard init
done
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
 sleep 1
 git merge --no-edit b$i
done
git branch merge1
git reset --hard init
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
 sleep 1
 git merge --no-edit b$i
done
```

Comment: Could you please give a simple example of your `[*]` remark? I guess it's the answer I am looking for, but I would like to reproduce it in a test repository first.

Comment: Outline is like: from some basic revision `B` steps should be like: 1) commit something,  2) create branch `b1`, 3) reset to `B`, repeat 1-3 several times creating branches b2, b3 etc., 4) reset to `B`, 5) merge `b1`, `b2`..., 6) create branch `merge1`, repeat 4,5, 7) create branch `merge2`.

Comment: What do you mean by `reset to B`? `git checkout master; git commit; git checkout -b b1; git reset head~1; git; git commit`. That will do nothing

Comment: added to the answer